# Steps to add ssl certificate in Virtual private server and PHP configurations

Tags: ssl-certificate, php.ini

I have a Virtual Private Server(VPS) in CtrlS. I need to add SSL certificate to my VPS server.

1. What are the steps to add SSL Certificate on VPS?
2. In my Web Application i have lot of PHP files to respond client Requests.Shall i need to configure my PHP after installing SSL certificate in my VPS?

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more on which environment you are running (Operating System, software stack, ..). Please first try to search for a manual for the software you are using as your question maybe directly answered by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your apache config file, and add the following lines

```
ServerName yourservername
DocumentRoot yourdocumentroot
ServerAdmin
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile yourpathtoyour .crt file
SSLCertificateKeyFile yourpathtoyour .key file
SSLCertificateChainFile pathtoyour .crt file
</VirtualHost>
```

Assuming you did all the right procedures to get an SSL Certificate , that is first get the key file generating at your system and then use it for get the crt file with your SSL certificate provider.

Once done this you dont need to reconfigure anything at your PHP

Comment: is it possible to add SSL Certificate myself without buy certificate from any Service Provider?

Comment: yes, you can create a self signed certificate, check this link http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html still , does not provide all features of the comercial ones